# Need help with jQuery ToolTip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

http://rndnext.blogspot.com/2009/02/jquery-ajax-tooltip.html

I want to implement something like the link above. Now this pops up the box's fetching data from some page, using PageID and what not. I want the content of that popup box to have simple HTML stuff in it and it will be bound later. The one above has got Ajax that I am not familiar with.

What do I need to change in the code? All I want is a simple pop up box that looks exactly like the one above, opens up the same way and all, BUT has got simple HTMl stuff in it. What and where do I make changes?

Comment: While I imagine that you'll get some answers, you might have a better response if you try to implement this yourself (even if it involves directly copying and pasting their code, and making adjustments to see what works), and then ask us about specific problems. As it is it feels like you're asking us to do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you haven't posted any of your attempts at doing this yourself, I will try to help you out.

If I understand correctly, you want to get rid of the AJAX and just add normal HTML right?
Well, I will at least tell you where to put your HTML to get you started.

You see on their website, at line 51 it says:

```
$('#personPopupContent').html('&nbsp;');
```

You can change the nbsp bit to any HTML you want.
For example:

```
$('#personPopupContent').html('<strong>My strong text</strong>');
```

You can also delete from lines 53 to 74 where it says:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'personajax.aspx',
    data: 'page=' + pageID + '&guid=' + currentID,
    success: function(data)
    {
      // Verify that we're pointed to a page that returned the expected results.
      if (data.indexOf('personPopupResult') < 0)
      {
          $('#personPopupContent').html('<span >Page ' + pageID + ' did not return a valid result for person ' + currentID + '.Please have your administrator check the error log.</span>');
      }

      // Verify requested person is this person since we could have multiple ajax
      // requests out if the server is taking a while.
      if (data.indexOf(currentID) > 0)
      {                  
          var text = $(data).find('.personPopupResult').html();
          $('#personPopupContent').html(text);
      }
    }
});
```

Since you won't be using it.

I hope that helped you.